# How to retrieve contact's thumbnail

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm coding an activity that show a list of contact. My list has two fields per entry: the *ID* column and the *DISPLAY_NAME* column of the table identified by the uri *ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI*. To display the result of the query I use a *SimpleCursorAdapter*.

Now I want to add a new field to each entry, the thumbnail of the contact. So I added to the query's projection the column name *PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI*, but no picture are inserted. If I add the column name *PHOTO_URI* the picture inserted is too big.

So, I want to use a *SimpleCursorAdapter* to display contact's entry, where each one have the ID of the contact, the DISPLAY_NAME, and a thumbnail.

Second, if a thumbnail is missing I want to insert a default thumbnail, for example look [this](http://ngo-hung.com/files/images/contact_list_view_1.png).

Can someone explain me how can I do it? Where I can read something about this topic? It should be a standard task!

Answer (score 0):

Loading images in a list view is not a standard task. It requires an implementation of lazy loading with a cache of photos.

You can check how android does it in the People app here
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/contacts/common/list/ContactEntryListAdapter.java#ContactEntryListAdapter.getPhotoLoader%28%29

They you an asynchronous photo loader with a photo cache
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/contacts/common/ContactPhotoManager.java#ContactPhotoManagerImpl.loadThumbnail%28android.widget.ImageView%2Clong%2Cboolean%2Ccom.android.contacts.common.ContactPhotoManager.DefaultImageProvider%29